# Cucumber not closing IE8 or Chrome on a Windows7 VM

Tags: ruby, webdriver, cucumber, jruby, watir-webdriver

I have a suite of cucumber scripts that execute against our web apps.  When I run the scripts against IE8 and Chrome they run fine but when it comes to closing the browser it can't.

Here is the stack trace I get:

Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused

```
    initialize at org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:122
          open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1179
       connect at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762
       timeout at org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:105
       connect at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762
      do_start at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755
         start at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:744
         start at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:743
       request at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1292
       request at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51
  response_for at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83
       request at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39
          call at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40
   raw_execute at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:619
       execute at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:597
          quit at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:193
          quit at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:48
          quit at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:168
         close at C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:135
        (root) at C:/Users/explorys/Documents/workspace/qa-cucumber/features/support/hooks.rb:25
```

- We use jruby with our scripts.

Here is the code that closes the browser:

```
at_exit do
  if !browser.nil?
    browser.close
  end
end
```

Here is a list of the gems:

> activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.12)
>
> activerecord (3.2.12)
>
> activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2.1)
>
> activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2.1)
>
> activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.12)
>
> arel (3.0.2)
>
> builder (3.0.4)
>
> childprocess (0.3.8)
>
> commonwatir (4.0.0)
>
> composite_primary_keys (5.0.12)
>
> cucumber (1.2.1)
>
> diff-lcs (1.2.1, 1.1.3)
>
> fastercsv (1.5.5)
>
> ffi (1.3.1 java)
>
> gherkin (2.11.6 java)
>
> hbase-jruby (0.2.2 java)
>
> i18n (0.6.1)
>
> jdbc-mysql (5.1.22.1)
>
> jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
>
> json (1.7.7 java)
>
> linecache (0.46 java)
>
> mime-types (1.22)
>
> multi_json (1.6.0)
>
> rake (10.0.2)
>
> rest-client (1.6.7)
>
> rspec (2.12.0)
>
> rspec-core (2.12.2)
>
> rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
>
> rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
>
> ruby-debug-base (0.10.5.rc3 java)
>
> ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta17, 0.4.17.beta16)
>
> rubyzip (0.9.9)
>
> selenium-webdriver (2.32.1, 2.29.0)
>
> sys-uname (0.9.1)
>
> tzinfo (0.3.35)
>
> watir (4.0.2)
>
> watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
>
> websocket (1.0.7)
>
> win32-process (0.7.2)
>
> xml-object (0.9.93)
>
> xml-simple (1.1.2)

Comment: Based on the stack the issue is at the webdriver level or below.  Interesting to see rest-client in there, as far as I know webdriver doesn't depend on that gem, so strange it is in the callstack

Comment: Chuck, Thank you for responding.  We are using the rest-client with cucumber to test REST services.  I don't understand why this is happening.  I have other scripts that don't use the cucumber framework and open and close all browsers without issue.

Comment: I've used that gem for the same thing.  but didn't share the cucumber directories so never ran UI facing tests with the same env.rb etc..

Comment: Seeing rest.client in the call stack of the error makes me think it's somehow getting into the mix and maybe causing an issue.  Just to rule it out,  I'd try the following.  Comment out the require line for rest-client.  Use cucumber taqs to run a small subset of the tests which would expose the problem closing the browser and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Hi Chuck.  I commented that require statement for gem and got the same callstack without the reference to the rest-client.  I downgraded my selenium-driver to 2.27.2 just to see if that might be the problem but that wasn't it either.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure here.  can you duplicate it from IRB if you just try to open and close the browser?   seems like we need to start ruling stuff out..